# 7-Zip not excluding files as expected

Tags: 7-zip

I am trying to simply extract some .tar archives to their current directory using 7-Zip - excluding archives called 'dl.tar'. It should be straight forward - however the exclude flag is not working.

Here is the command;

```
7z x *.tar -x!dl.tar
```

The response;

```
J:\2016-Q4\Mapinfo\Europe\Albania>7z x *.tar -x!dl.tar

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18

Processing archive: dl.tar
```

Is there something simple i am doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the `-ax` switch: `Specifies archives to be excluded from the operation.` - `-ax!dl.tar`

Comment: Ah that worked perfectly. Don't know how i missed that switch. Thanks!

Comment: @Aki : It looks like you have an excellent opportunity for easy reputation points.  Post that comment as an official answer, and it looks highly likely to be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously mentioned in my comment, you can use the `-ax` switch.

```
7z x *.tar -ax!dl.tar
```

> Specifies archives to be excluded from the operation.

https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/ar_exclude.htm